# How to use vuex getter after async api call

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, async-await, state, vuex

What is the proper way to call a getter in vuex after you dispatched an async action which mutated the state?

I created an example snippet to illustrate what I mean. As you can see, `getLastNameByName()` fails because `state.persons` is empty. The weird thing is, that if I print `state.persons` in that getter, it prints the array after api call.

Expected behaviour is that `getLastNameByName('John')` returns `{name: 'John', lastname: 'Smith'}`

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    persons: []
  },

  getters: {
    getLastNameByName: (state) => (name) => {

      // console.log(state.persons) returns the state, yet I cannot call .find on it 
      return state.persons.find(element => {
        return element.name === name
      }).lastname
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    setPersons: (state, payload) => {
      state.persons = [...payload]
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async getPeople({commit}) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(async () => {
             commit('setPersons', [{
               name: 'John',
               lastname: 'Smith'
            }, {
            name: 'Sarah',
            account: 'Appleseed'
          }])

           resolve();
         }, 1000)
      })
  }
  }
})

new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getPeople').then( () =>  { 
      console.log(this.$store.getters.getLastNameByName('John'))
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

setTimeout() don't returns awaitable object. Check with promise:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    persons: []
  },

  getters: {
    getLastNameByName: (state) => (name) => {
      return state.persons.find(element => {
        return element.name === name
      }).lastname
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    setPersons: (state, payload) => {
      state.persons = [...payload]
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async getPeople({commit}) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(async () => {
             commit('setPersons', [{
               name: 'John',
               lastname: 'Smith'
            }, {
            name: 'Sarah',
            account: 'Appleseed'
          }])

           resolve();
         }, 1000)
      })
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getPeople').then(() => {
       console.log(this.$store.getters.getLastNameByName('John'));
    })
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Anyway direct handling async calls to store isn't a proper way. I think in this case better solutions is to `watch` store state or use `computed` properties.

Comment: My bad, I thought I correctly recreated my problem in this manner. The example indeed works fine now, so I guess it's because of something else in my project. Could you elaborate a bit more on your suggested better solution? Set a watcher on the `state.persons` and call the getter in that watch? The problem is, however, that I need to use that getter in another action.

Answer (score 1):

Tried on jsbin.com with few improvements and no problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Vue example</title>

<div id="app">
  <show-person
    :name="getLastName('John')"
  ></show-person>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>

<script>
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    persons: []
  },

  getters: {
    getLastName: state => name => {
      return state.persons.length
        ? state.persons.find(element => {
            return element.name === name
          }).lastname
        : ''
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    setPersons: (state, payload) => {
      state.persons = [...payload]
    }
  },

  actions: {
    getPeople: ({ commit }) => new Promise(res => {
      const data = [
        {name: 'John', lastname: 'Smith'},
        {name: 'Sarah', account: 'Appleseed'}
      ]
      setTimeout(() => {
        commit('setPersons', data)
        res()
      }, 1000)
    })
  }
})

const ShowPerson = {
  functional: true,
  render: (h, ctx) => h('p', ctx.props.name)
}

new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',

  components: {
    ShowPerson
  },

  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters([
      'getLastName'
    ])
  },

  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapActions([
      'getPeople'
    ])
  },

  created () {
    this.getPeople()
  }
})
</script>
```